# How to string with spaces as input and store in char array in java

Tags: string

```
   String w="ab cd";
  // String w=sc.next(); need this line to work
   int length=w.length();
   char arr2[]=new char[length];

   for(int j=0;j<length;j++)
   {
       arr2[j]=w.charAt(j);
   }
   for(int i=0;i<arr2.length;i++)
   {
       System.out.println(arr2[i]);
   }
```

This code works fine for string literal but fails when i take input at runtime.Any solution for it? It only prints ab i.e. before space

Comment: use toCharArray(w); it will work\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the demo program

```
public class demo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String w=sc.nextLine();
    char arr[]=w.toCharArray();
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Thanks , the mistake was using next() in place of nextLine() for the desired output.